# Not receiving SMS from short numbers on Xiaomi Mi Max 3 (MIUI)

Tags: sms, xiaomi, miui

Phone doesn't receive 2fa messages, bank codes, etc.

This is chinese Xiaomi Mi Max 3 with unlocked bootloader which came with global 10.0.1.0 miui (Android 8.1).

What I've tried:

- checking sms center number
- disabling MIUI optimizations
- changing settings of messaging app (disabling block list, enabling miui sms)
- disabling volte
- installing alternative sms apps
- changing sim slots
- reflashing global 10.0.2.0 miui via fastboot with full wipe

I was able to fix this on another Mi Max 3 with chinese 8.8.9 ROM by disabling MIUI optimizations if I remember correctly, but it doesn't work on this one...

Any idea how to fix this?